# How to compute the zoom level against returned markers?

Tags: android

I'd like to know if there is already a way to know from a given set of markers, the zoom I should apply to the map or do I have to do it my self? (This depends on the resolution so i expected to find it in MapView because it knows its boundaries.)

Answer (score 4):

```
int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for( GeoPoint l : points ) {
    minLat  = Math.min( l.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
    minLong = Math.min( l.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
    maxLat  = Math.max( l.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
    maxLong = Math.max( l.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
}

mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work at all the zoom is huge.

Comment: Whoops, you're right that version was broken.  I've edited the answer to use fewer temporary objects and also work :)

Comment: Could anybody tell that what about points, what it is suppose to be ?

Comment: If you are dealing with GPS points then you need to convert them to geopoint by </br>

`(int)Math.round(lat * 1E6)`

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to do a method my self, it doesn't work perfectly but it seems sufficient (maybe I should round the quotient up to have the real value):

```
private void adjustZoomToMarkers(ArrayList<GeoLocationFlag> flags) {
    GeoPoint mapCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
    int lat = mapCenter.getLatitudeE6(), lng = mapCenter.getLongitudeE6();
    int farestLat = 0, farestLng = 0;
    for (GeoLocationFlag geoLocationFlag : flags) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "lat: " + geoLocationFlag.getLat());
        int flagLatDistance = Math.abs(geoLocationFlag.getLat() - lat);
        if (farestLat < flagLatDistance)
            farestLat = flagLatDistance;

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "lng: " + geoLocationFlag.getLng());
        int flagLngDistance = Math.abs(geoLocationFlag.getLng() - lng);
        if (farestLng < flagLngDistance)
            farestLng = flagLngDistance;
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "farest: " + farestLat + "," + farestLng);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "spans: " + mapView.getLatitudeSpan() + "," + mapView.getLongitudeSpan());

    // compute how many times this screen we are far on lat
    float latQuotient = (float) farestLat / ((float) mapView.getLatitudeSpan() / 2);
    // compute how many times this screen we are far on lng
    float lngQuotient = (float) farestLng / ((float) mapView.getLongitudeSpan() / 2);

    int zoom = 0;
    if (latQuotient > 1 || lngQuotient > 1) {
        // must zoom out
        float qutient = Math.max((int) latQuotient, (int) lngQuotient);
        while ((qutient / 2) > 1) {
            qutient = qutient / 2;
            zoom--;
        }
    } else {
        float qutient = Math.max((int) (1 / (float) latQuotient), (int) (1 / (float) lngQuotient));
        while ((qutient / 2) > 1) {
            qutient = qutient / 2;
            zoom++;
        }

    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Zoom found " + zoom);

    int zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel();
    mapController.setZoom(zoomLevel + zoom);
}
```

Best regards,
Zied Hamdi

Answer (score 0):

As guessed when I was writing the answer above: when the quotient is eg. 9, it means you need more than 4 iterations to see it:
 so just correst both lines:

```
while ((qutient / 2) > 0.5) {
```

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi

Answer (score 0):

I like your code that is a lot shorter ;-), maybe I should only avoid creating new instances in the for loop to have the min and max points...

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi